# Instead of prompt a choice from images for rock, paper, scissors, etc game

Tags: javascript, image, getelementbyid, prompt

I'm new with javascript and working on a simple rock, paper, scissors, lizard, spock game.
I want to let the user choose from 5 images instead of fill it in a prompt. 
Does anyone know how I can make that? The alert and confirm messages should also be a < p > or something like that eventually.

```
var userChoice = prompt("Fill in one of these:\n\n- Rock\n- Paper\n- Scissors\n- Lizard\n- Spock \n");

userChoice = userChoice.toLowerCase();

var computerChoice = Math.random();

if (computerChoice < 0.20) {
    computerChoice = "rock";
} else if(computerChoice <= 0.40) {
    computerChoice = "paper";
} else if(computerChoice <= 0.60) {
    computerChoice = "scissors";
} else if(computerChoice <= 0.80) {
    computerChoice = "lizard";
} else {
    computerChoice = "spock";
}

if ((userChoice === "rock")||(userChoice === "paper")||(userChoice === "scissors")||(userChoice === "lizard")||(userChoice === "spock")){
alert("Computer chose: " + computerChoice);
} else { if (alert('Oops! Looks like you made a typo!')){}
else {document.location.reload(true); }};

var compare = function (choice1, choice2) {

if (choice1 === choice2) {
alert("The result is a tie!");
}


else if (choice1 === "rock") {
    if (choice2 === "scissors") {
        alert("Rock crushes scissors! You win!");
    } else if (choice2 === "paper") {
        alert("Paper covers rock! You lose!");
    } else if (choice2 === "lizard") {
        alert("Rock crushes lizard! You win!");
    } else {
        alert("Spock vaporizes rock! You lose!");
    }
}

else if (choice1 === "paper") {
    if (choice2 === "scissors") {
        alert("Scissors cuts paper! You lose!");
    } else if (choice2 === "rock") {
        alert("Paper covers rock! You win!");
    } else if (choice2 === "lizard") {
        alert("Lizard eats paper! You lose!");
    } else {
        alert("Paper disproves Spock! You Win!");
    }
}

else if (choice1 === "scissors") {
    if (choice2 === "paper") {
        alert("Scissors cuts paper! You win!");
    } else if (choice2 === "rock") {
        alert("Rock crushes scissors! You lose");
    } else if (choice2 === "lizard") {
        alert("Scissors decapitates lizard! You win!");
    } else {
        alert("Spock smashes scissors! You lose!");
    }
}


else if (choice1 === "lizard") {
    if (choice2 === "scissors") {
        alert("Scissors decapitates lizard! You lose!");
    } else if (choice2 === "rock") {
        alert("Rock crushes lizard! You lose!");
    } else if (choice2 === "paper") {
        alert("Lizard eats paper! You win!");
    } else {
        alert("Lizard poinsons Spock! You win!");
    }
}


else if (choice1 === "spock") {
    if (choice2 === "scissors") {
        alert("Spock smashes scissors! You win!");
    } else if (choice2 === "rock") {
        alert("Spock vaporizes rock! You win!");
    } else if (choice2 === "lizard") {
        alert("Lizard poinsons Spock! You lose!");
    } else {
        alert("Paper disproves Spock! You lose!");
    }
}
};

compare(userChoice, computerChoice);

if ((userChoice === "rock")||(userChoice === "paper")||(userChoice === "scissors")||(userChoice === "lizard")||(userChoice === "spock")){
if(confirm('Do you want to play Again?')){document.location.reload(true);}
}
```

Comment: This doesn't really belong in StackOverlow. This isn't meant to let other people write code for you. But since I'm in a good mood I'll help you on the way.

Comment: Insert images into anchor with `rel` attribute containing value of each choice

Comment: You'd need to set the 5 images up in your html and attach a click handler event to them. Seen as you've made a good attempt at starting your project, I suggest you look here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/click You look like you need pointing in the right direction more than being spoon fed code so hopefully this will be of use!

Comment: I tried this: 
HTML <img id="rock" src="img/rock.png" width="300" height="300" alt="rock" /> 
JAVASCRIPT rock.onclick = function() {
return userChoice = "rock";
} 
But that didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You can attach onclick handlers with `addEventLister` function. You can use a map of possible combinations, it's much shorter and more readable. Moreover, you can avoid writing duplicit combinations - eg. rock -> scissors, scissors -> rock

```
var combinations = {
  'scissors': {
    'paper': 'cuts',
    'lizard': 'decapitates'
  },
  'paper': {
    'rock': 'covers',
    'spock': 'disproves'
  },
  'rock': {
    'lizard': 'crushes',
    'scissors': 'crushes'
  },
  'lizard': {
    'spock': 'poisons',
    'eats': 'paper'
  },
  'spock': {
    'smashes': 'scissors',
    'rock': 'vaporizes'
  }
}
var calculate = function (computer, player)
{
  if (combinations[computer][player]) {
    return computer + ' ' + combinations[computer][player] + ' ' + player + '! You lose!';
  } else if (combinations[player][computer]) {
    return player + ' ' + combinations[player][computer] + ' ' + computer + '! You win!';
  }
  return 'The result is a tie!';
}
var computerChoice = function()
{
  var choice = Math.random();
  if (choice < 0.20) {
        return "rock";
  } else if(choice <= 0.40) {
        return "paper";
  } else if(choice <= 0.60) {
        return "scissors";
  } else if(choice <= 0.80) {
        return "lizard";
  } else {
        return "spock";
  }
}
window.onload = function ()
{
  var links = document.getElementsByClassName('rpssl');
  for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
    links[i].addEventListener('click', function()
    {
      var comp = computerChoice();
      alert("Computer chose: " + comp);
      alert(calculate(comp, this.getAttribute('rel')))
    })
  }
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9jJAd/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it:

**HTML**

```
<img onclick="compare('rock')" src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/animals/Rock/" alt="" />
<img onclick="compare('paper')" src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/animals/Paper/" alt="" />
<img onclick="compare('scissors')" src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/animals/Scissors/" alt="" />
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/qYrq9/)**